# How to stream audio from javascript frontend to server using websockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket, streaming, webm, web-mediarecorder

I have a solution to stream using MediaRecorder API:

```js
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8765");
socket.binaryType = "blob";
socket.onopen = function (event) {
     const video = document.querySelector('audio');
     video.onplay = function() {
          mediaStream = video.captureStream();
          mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream, {
                mimeType: 'audio/webm'
          });
          mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', (e) => {
                socket.send(e.data);
          });
          mediaRecorder.start(1000);
     };
};
```

But it doesn't play on my server (For example I use ffmpeg to record stream to file) because MediaRecorder API puts headers only to the first chunk. How can I put webm headers to every chunk?

Comment: You may want to follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61459893/html5-video-stream-from-websocket-via-mediasource-and-mediasourcebuffer